# Accessing Jaeger /tracing on from k8s cluster returns index.html and 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, istio, putty, jaeger

I have a Kubernetes cluster which runs with Istio as a service mesh and load balancing provided by Metallb. I have 4 Istio addons (Prometheus, Kiali, Grafana, and Jaeger) running on the cluster in the istio namespace, but running firefox on the virtual machine is relatively slow and I also don't want to rely on the "istioctl dashboard" command in order to access my monitoring tools.

I've successfully been able to access Kiali and Grafana by tunneling in with putty and utilizing Istio ingressgateway with Gateway/Virtual service resources similar to those found in istio documentation here - https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/. The istio ingressgateway pod is listening on 10.10.1.10 and my putty tunnel is directed to 10.10.1.10:80 with a source port of 90. Everything is done in http for testing at this time

I've listed my specific configuration below -

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: tracing-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-tracing
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tracing-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - tracing-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: tracing
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: tracing
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: tracing
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
---
```

Whenever I attempt to access Jaeger by hitting the /tracing , however, I always receive a 503 service unavailable error. I know that the application can be functional though because if I run the istioctl dashboard jaeger command I can access it through the VM's firefox browser. I'm wondering what I need to configure within Jaeger to allow me to access it

Initially, when working with Jaeger I attempted to use a gateway/virtualsservice configuration that was identical to what worked for Grafana and Kiali but replacing names/ports/prefixes. which is shown below -

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grafana-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - grafana-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /grafana
    route:
    - destination:
        host: grafana
        port:
          number: 3000
```

When running this for jaeger I only ever received HTTP 503 responses. After trying different combinations of ports I used the yaml definition from the Istio page listed in the link above, changing only the hosts line since I don't have a domain and everything is IP based.

At this point, when I navigate to /tracing using my putty tunnel, it returns a blank page which, if inspected, is the jaegers index.html page. Inspecting the page shows that it attempts to redirect to jaeger_tracing but returns the net::ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable) code shown in the screenshot below [/tracing_error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwNgS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround solution was found by running the kubectl port-forward command on port 16686 but the same can be done with the istioctl dashboard jaeger command.

I ran one of them in the background and tunneled to localhost using my putty instance using the url /jaeger_tracing which is defined in my jaeger manifest. From there I could hit jaeger from my local instance without the sluggish VM performance.